# Can I append to altair Tooltips instead of creating from scratch?

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I've been creating tooltips in altair by using the `tooltip` encoding. Is there a way I can 'add to' the default tooltip (that contains the x, y, color, facet values etc), instead of having to type out every single field I want?

Typing out every single field gets onerous when 1/ I have a chart with many facets, 2/ I heavily edited the x or y fields, and have to repeat the edits.

For example, this is how I'm constructing the tooltip currently:

```py
b = (
    alt.Chart(df)
       .transform_fold(["facetA", "facetB", "facetC"])
       .mark_line()
       .encode(
           x=alt.X("date:T", title="Date", axis=alt.Axis(orient="top", format="%Y-%m-%d")),
           y=alt.Y("value:Q"),
           facet=alt.Facet("key:N", columns=3),
           tooltip=[alt.Tooltip("date", title="Date", format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                    "facetA",
                    "facetB",
                    "facetC",
                    "interesting_detail"])
       .properties(width=125)
       .resolve_axis(x="independent")
       .resolve_scale(x="independent")
)
```

I am interested in any solution that will allow me to just say, "the tooltip should have all the possible fields + `interesting_detail`, instead of having to reproduce every single field + `interesting_detail` (including having to redo the customization on my x field).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is possible, you either have to use the default tooltip or manually specified field.